# Class variable being assigned null

Tags: c#, class, variables, methods

I have a main form where I'm assigning some variables and passing them to myclass.cs. I need to use class variables in myclass.cs as I need to utilize these variables in several places of that class.

I can see the variables correctly in the CustomerParams method of myclass.cs so I know they're getting there. However, they always return as null if I call them right after the InitializeComponent(); of myclass.cs. If I call them in another event handler such as with a button click in myclass.cs then they always return the first variable assigned and never get updated as I select different ones from the listbox in mainform (even thought he CustomerParams method continues to update as expected). What am I doing wrong?

mainform.cs

```
    private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox != null)
        {
            string customerName = (listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();

            contentPanel.Controls.Add(mc);

            mc.CustomerParams(customerName, customerId);
        }
    }
```

myclass.cs

```
public partial class MyClass : UserControl
{
    private int _customerId { get; set; }
    private string _customerName {get; set;}
    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Shows null values!
        Console.WriteLine("Values: " + _customerName + "(" + _customerId + ")");
    }

    public void CustomerParams(string customerName, int customerId)
    {
        _customerName = customerName;
        _customerId = customerId;

        // Shows correct values!
        Console.WriteLine("Values-Method: " + _customerName + "(" + _customerId + ")");

    }

    private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only shows the initial value even when the SelectedIndex in mainform.cs changes
        Console.WriteLine("Values-Button: " + _customerName + "(" + _customerId + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `AffiliateProperties` ?

Comment: I had changed the method names and variables to be generic for posting online, that was an oversight I had forgotten to change that reference as well. I have updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? MVC? WinForms?

Comment: This is for WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. What I ended up doing was in my main form I created a static method where I assign the variables, then call that static method for my button click as well as in myclass where I then assign to variables.

Comment: Its too bad you had to resort to using static variable. I started with static variables but had to remove them and now run into the issue you describe. The problem with static variable is it is set for a whole application container, which doesn't seem appropriate in a case like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting null after InitializeComponent() because nothing has been assigned to the variables.  They have a value in CustomerParams, because you are setting them to the parameters that come through the method.  The only place you are assigning values to these variables is in the CustomerParams method, so they will never change value outside of that method.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem very complete.

Comment: If this were the case then I wouldn't be receiving initial values in every other method of myclass.cs. I don't understand why the value doesn't get updated each time the CustomerParams method is run or why I am only getting nulls when I reference the varialbes immediately following InitializeComponent()?  Since I'm creating the variable at the class level then I believe it should be updated each time I call CustomerParams but that is not the case.

Comment: Did I miss something, BradleyDotNET?  Seems pretty simple to me.

Comment: @doby48: So you're saying that you are calling CustomerParams and passing it new values, and then after that the properties _customerId and _customerName still have their old values?

Comment: My app works like this. mainform.cs opens and user must click a listbox item, which in turn calls CustomerParams. At this point variable is update in CustomerParams method as well as all other methods in myclass.cs (though still null after InitializeComponent()). Then the user selects another item from the listbox which in turn again calls CustomerParams. The variable again updates correctly in that method, but this time the rest of the methods with myclass.css do not get updated again.

Comment: Class variables are not held in individual methods. There is one variable for each at the class level and the methods simply access them. So when they get updated, they are not updated for individual methods, but for the entire class. So at any moment in time, the variable cannot have one value for one method and a different value for another method. The variable has one value and a method either can or cannot access it. It's hard to say exactly what you are seeing without additional information.

Comment: This is the reason I'm so confused. Because I am seeing the value within CustomerParams method every time without fail. That same variable (though this time declared at the class level and referenced in other methods of myclass.cs) only gets updated the first time CustomerParmams is called but never again on subsequent calls. Why would that happen? Also since the variable is assigned on the class level which is evident since all methods can see some value at least (though sometimes stale), why does this same value when referenced immediatly after InitializeComponent() always return null?

Comment: What additional information would you like to see that I have not yet provided?

Comment: I don't know what else you can provide other than being able to actually debug through the program with you. There has to be something else going on. Just for kicks, try using fields instead of properties for the two variables.  Also, why are you using InitializeComponent() in your constructor? I would think you could do away with the constructor all together unless you want to use it to give the two variables initial values. Unless you need to initialize the program there, eliminating your constructor might actually solve your problem.

Comment: I switched to fields and got the same results. I'm using InitializeComponent() because this class has a lot of user controls that are loaded in a panel of the main form.

Comment: I didn't get your message because you forgot the @ symbol :). You have the first part of the problem right, but I believe that there is confusion about him creating a new instance of "MyClass" each time that hasn't been included/discussed yet. IIRC, you always call InitializeComponent in a UserControl constructor :) Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning c# (coming from C++) and I ran into this same issue. The solution is to declare the class variables STATIC. I guess since the class is never instantiated, the variables need to be static. Explained here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx#Anchor_0